# Newbie question on user interface of sql developer query resutls tabs functionality

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

on Query Results tabs I am able to manage what columns are displayed in table. However, I can't find a way to save this column state, so each time I come back to working on this table I must hide dozens of irrelevant columns to my issue, hidden the columns makes it easier to analyze the data, however, the columns I want to hide are not all next to each other, so it's an effort to go through and pick out the columns to hide each time.  If there is already a post on this please share as I wasn't able to find it, thanks.

don't know what to try, can't find reference

Answer (score 0):

If you use:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

Then you will get all columns.

If you only want certain columns then name the columns in your query (and then you don't need to hide the unwanted ones):

```sql
SELECT column1,
       column4,
       column17,
       column42
FROM   table_name
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't create view for this purpose, it's an enterprise environment, just wanting to know the functionality of UI if there's a way to save a 'Query Results' tab state.

Comment: On the select columns, thanks

Comment: I just found that I can select multiple top row fields by shift and select or ctrl click and then right click on column headers and there is an option to copy selected column headers, then go back into editor and paste and use in select statement. This works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Would a **view** do any good?

This is your *original* query which returns bunch of columns:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from emp e join dept d on d.deptno = e.deptno
  3  where rownum <= 3;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM     DEPTNO     DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------------- -------------
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09-JUN-81     2572.5                    10         10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17-NOV-81       5250                    10         10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23-JAN-82       1365                    10         10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
```

If you create a view which selects only relevant ones ...

```
SQL> create or replace view v_emp as
  2    select d.dname, e.ename, e.job, d.loc, e.sal
  3    from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno;

View created.
```

... then querying that view returns only desired subset of columns ...

```
SQL> select * From v_emp where rownum <= 3;

DNAME          ENAME      JOB       LOC                  SAL
-------------- ---------- --------- ------------- ----------
ACCOUNTING     CLARK      MANAGER   NEW YORK          2572.5
ACCOUNTING     KING       PRESIDENT NEW YORK            5250
ACCOUNTING     MILLER     CLERK     NEW YORK            1365

SQL>
```

... and you don't have to hide anything.

Answer (score 0):

Prompted by Select responses I went back to UI and discovered the following:

I just found that I can select multiple top row fields by shift and select or ctrl click and then right click on column headers and there is an option to copy selected column headers, then go back into editor and paste and use in select statement. This works fine for me.